# What is the correct syntax to classify ages into groups using IF statements in Google Sheets?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, multiple-conditions, categorization

[Why am i getting "formula parse error" when I try to classify the ages (column H) into groups using the following formula? And is there a better way? Thanks for your assistance:

=IF (H19<20, “0-19”, IF ((H19>=20 AND H19<40), “20-39”, IF ((H19>=40 AND H19<60), “40-59”, IF ((H19>=60 AND H19<70), “60-69”, IF (H19>=70, ">= 70", “WRONG”)))))

I was expecting to output the Age column into strings based on my category definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portions that you have formatted as `(H19>=20 AND H19<40)` should be changed to `AND(H19>=20, H19<40)`. Your final formula should then be:

```
=IF(H19<20, “0-19”,
  IF(AND(H19>=20, H19<40), “20-39”,
  IF(AND(H19>=40, H19<60), “40-59”,
  IF(AND(H19>=60, H19<70), “60-69”,
  IF(H19>=70, ">= 70", “WRONG”)))))
```

Alternatively:

```
=IFS(OR(NOT(ISNUMBER(H19)),H19<0), "WRONG",
  H19<20, "0-19",
  AND(H19>=20, H19<40), "20-39",
  AND(H19>=40, H19<60), "40-59",
  AND(H19>=60, H19<70), "60-69",
  H19>=70, ">= 70")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough syntax. It did the job well!

Answer (score 3):

Can you try:

```
=let(Σ,{0  ,"0-19";
        20 ,"20-39";
        40 ,"40-59";
        60 ,"60-69";
        70 ,">=70"},
     vlookup(H19,Σ,2,1))
```

- uses ***[VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)*** approx. match capability

Comment: Thanks for introducing a new concept to me "let". It didn't end up exactly doing what i was execting though. I may have to play around with it!

Comment: If possible please do share a test sheet with sample data and expected output(manually entered) as as for us to check it out directly.

Comment: @Roya I personally like the `let` approach more than my own. If it's the #N/A error that you didn't expect/desire, you can wrap it in `=ifna(let(), "WRONG")`

Comment: @milklizard, good idea. I will do this!